# Colocar el boton de primera columna Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Tengo una tabla, con datatable y quiero mostrar el boton de la primera columna como aparece referenciado en la pagina de [Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/), he leido un poco el manual pero no consigo esa parte

Quiero agregarle ese boton verde con el signo + como se muestra en la img
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

****------EDITADO-----****

Gracias a él comentario de **David081** logre tener la documentacion con este enlace [row_details](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

Mi problema esta en que estoy haciendo la solicitud por POST  estoy teniendo inconveniente para reflejar mis datos en la tabla.
[image: Vista Tabla],

Al darle F12 me da el siguiente msj

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero acotar que necesito realizar esto por POST ya que agregare más campo y hare un búsqueda más personalizada.

Anexo codigo View

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Anexo Codigo Js

```
var url = window.location.origin;

        var datatableClass = {
            "Id": 1,
            "Nombre": "127.0.0.1",
            "Apellidos": "ADMIN",
            "Correo": null,
            "Fecha": "20/10/2022",
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "/DataTable/logsPost/" + datatableClass,
            cache: "false",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { datatableClass: datatableClass }
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            var js = JSON.stringify(response);
            var dtJson = response;
            var length = dtJson.data.length;

            if (length > 0) {

                    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                        jsonData: js,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                className: 'dt-control',
                                orderable: false,
                                data: null,
                                defaultContent: '',
                            },
                            { data: 'Id' },
                            { data: 'Nombre' },
                            { data: 'Apellidos' },
                            { data: 'Correo' },
                            { data: 'Fecha' },
                        ],
                        order: [[1, 'asc']],
                    });

                    //Add event listener for opening and closing details
                    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.dt-control', function () {
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var row = table.row(tr);

                        if (row.child.isShown()) {
                            // This row is already open - close it
                            row.child.hide();
                            tr.removeClass('shown');
                        } else {
                            // Open this row
                            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                            tr.addClass('shown');
                        }
                    });

                function format(d) {
                    return (
                        '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                        '<tr>' +
                        '<td>Data:</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        d.data +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                        '</table>'
                    );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("¡No hay Nada...!");
            }
        })
```

Este es el JSON que me devuelve mi controller

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Nombre": "Carlos",
        "Apellidos": "Marin",
        "Correo": "Carlos@gamil.com",
        "Fecha": "16/10/2022 23:27:09",
        "data": "Ingeniería de Sistemas. Se trata de ....."
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Nombre": "Crintian",
        "Apellidos": "Cuero",
        "Correo": "Crintian@gamil.com",
        "Fecha": "16/10/2022 23:27:09",
        "data": " La ingeniería civil es ..."
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Nombre": "Maria",
        "Apellidos": "Perez",
        "Correo": "Maria@gamil.com",
        "Fecha": "16/10/2022 23:27:09",
        "data": "La ingeniería económica hace referencia a ...."
    },
    {
        "Id": 4,
        "Nombre": "Pedro",
        "Apellidos": "Rodriguez",
        "Correo": "Pedro@gamil.com",
        "Fecha": "16/10/2022 23:27:09",
        "data": "La ingenieria financiera consiste en ...."
    },
    {
        "Id": 5,
        "Nombre": "Sergio",
        "Apellidos": "Garcia",
        "Correo": "Sergio@gamil.com",
        "Fecha": "16/10/2022 23:27:09",
        "data": "La Ingeniería Industrial es ...."
    }
]
```

}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese boton normalmente es para despelgar child rows, https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html  -aca esta la documentacion de datatables child rows, te faltan varios parametros por agregar

Comment: que me podra estar faltando ahora @David081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logre resolverlo, primero cambie mi lista en el controller para que no me devolviera los datos, sin el arreglo de data.

Es decir antes tenia esto

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Nombre": "Carlos",
        "Apellidos": "Marin",
        "Correo": "Carlos@gamil.com",
        "Fecha": "16/10/2022 23:27:09",
        "data": "Ingeniería de Sistemas. Se trata de ....."
   }]
}
```

Ahora me devuelve esto

```
   [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Nombre": "Carlos",
        "Apellidos": "Marin",
        "Correo": "Carlos@gamil.com",
        "Fecha": "16/10/2022 23:27:09",
        "data": "Ingeniería de Sistemas. Se trata de ....."
   }]
```

Posteriormente cambie mi linea de codigo

Esto

```
}).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
var js = JSON.stringify(response);
        var dtJson = response;
        var length = dtJson.data.length;

        if (length > 0) {

                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    jsonData: js,
```

Lo cambie por esto

```
}).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
//var js = JSON.stringify(response); //Lo comento por que no servira
        var dtJson = response;
        var length = dtJson.length;

        if (length > 0) {

                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    data: response,// Se cambia jsonData po data
```

Y Listo me muestra los datos correctamente